# Xcode - Fonts render differently because of NSWindow.StyleMask

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, fonts, nswindow

I use `fullSizeContentView` option (for NSWindow.styleMask) to have a transparent title bar. But by activating `fullSizeContentView`, alls fonts become thicker (take a look at the picture). I don't understand why, and how to avoid it.

Here is a picture to compare :

[image]

Any ideas ? Thanks in advance.

(I use Xcode 8.3.3, macOS Sierra 10.12.6)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but this is a kinda hand-wavy answer: I suspect the problem is your window / views gained “vibrancy” and that caused them to draw fonts differently. I’d check for vibrancy in the view debugger in Xcode 9.